# Dedicated server: why can't my JAVA application connect to my MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, linux, database-connection, debian

I got a dedicated server under Debian (amd64).

I installed a MySQL database with phpmyadmin and a Tomcat 6 server to deploy the JAVA application I just developed.

When I run this application once deployed, an exception is thrown: `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection`

I thought maybe my database credentials were wrong, so I wrote a little PHP script that I put on my remote Apache2 server, to see if it can connect to the same database, and yes: it can.

This is my PHP script:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mylogin', 'mypassword');
mysql_select_db('mydatabase', $link);
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM source');
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
var_dump($result);
```

The output is the list of the entries within my `source` table, alright. So why does my JAVA application can't connect to that *#@!?€* database?

This is my `pom.xml`:

```
<jdbc.type>mysql</jdbc.type>
<jdbc.driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</jdbc.driver>
<jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase</jdbc.url>
<jdbc.user>mylogin</jdbc.user>
<jdbc.password>mypassword</jdbc.password>
<hibernate.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</hibernate.dialect>
```

I also tried with

```
<jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase</jdbc.url>
```

and

```
<jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://012.345.678.9:3306/mydatabase</jdbc.url>
```

but it still doesn't work...

PS1: it works like a charm on a local server on my own machine.

PS2: everything is on the same remote machine (i.e. MySQL, Tomcat and Apache).

PS3: I bought the dedicated server to [Online](http://www.online.net/) (maybe a bit too french for some of you...).

PS4: don't hesitate to ask me more details, I dunno what could be usefull to you to help me solving that problem...

Comment: i think you need to have a mysql-connector jar file.

Comment: Is the database and the Tomcat engine running on the same machine? MySQL listens to localhost only by default.

Comment: @sp00m I'm a bit puzzled, you say that your Java code won't connect to the DB and then you post PHP code that DOES work ? :) please post your Java code so we can have a look (including imports)

Comment: Can you get a direct client session with the database on your server? Also, you could try adding the port to the url. The default for MySQL is 3306 I believe. You might also look for the underlying exception to see if that'll provide more direction.

Comment: @acecoder I do have one. It's a Maven project, so everything is managed via dependencies.
@Michael-O Yes, they are all running on the same machine (Tomcat, Mysql and Apache2). That's why I thought using `localhost` won't matter. As @Recursed proposed in his answer, I'll try with the @IP of the server instead, but if that were the problem, PHP wouldn't be able to connect too.
@alfasin My JAVA application is a whole Spring / Spring MVC / Hibernate one, so there is no specific line that I could show you. The problem occurs when I try to access for the first time one of the JPA repositories I use.

Comment: Have you logged into the remote server's database using the command line mysql client on that server?  It might be a problem with the account.

Comment: @Marvo I just tried, and yes: I can connect via `mysql -u mylogin -p`.

Comment: How is your datasource defined in your app?  Is it possible that on your local installation, you've got the datasource configured for Tomcat, but it's not configured that way on your remote server?  I'm not aware of a way to simply put those configuration settings in a pom file and have them magically get inserted into your datasource definition.  Maybe post more of your pom file?

Comment: @Marvo Sorry, but what do you mean by datasource? On my local server, I'm running under a Jetty server, no a Tomcat one.

Comment: Well, either Tomcat needs to define a datasource (like a database) in some manner so that applications can access it.  Or, your application has to define a datasource so that just that app can access it.  Google "configure a tomcat datasource" for a whole bunch of examples.  But there's so many different ways to do it, it's hard to give you a single answer.

Comment: But, again, perhaps post more of your pom file that demonstrates how those jdbc properties are used.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have missed the `port` in the `<jdbc.url>`.

You might modify the url from `<jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase</jdbc.url>` 
to `<jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:port/mydatabase</jdbc.url>`.

The port mostly is `3306`.

You could put in the ip of the MySQL server instead of `localhost` with the port and I think it should work.

Comment: I tried with `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase` and 
`jdbc:mysql://012.345.678.9:3306/mydatabase`, but none of them worked... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

There might be firewall rules in place.  Quite common on server installations.

Check if you can telnet to the mysql port.  If not, talk to the system administrator.

Comment: Sorry, I know how to ping an IP, but not how to telnet a port... I'm connected via SSH to the server. Can you give me the command I should try?

Comment: That should probably come from there. `telnet localhost 3306` tells `Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refuse` and `telnet 012.345.678.9 3306` tells `JHost 'myreverse' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL serverConnection closed by foreign host`. So you said I should contact the system administrator?

Comment: Sounds like you need help.  The latter message is fixable by the MySQL DBA.

Answer (score 0):

I finally deployed it using `mvn tomcat:deploy`, and it worked. I was uploading the WAR file via the manager/html interface of Tomcat before.